# In Unity, Just playing an animation in UGUI will cause GC allocation

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

Looping animation is assigned to Animator of that LampItem_0.

[image]

The content of the animation is to change Image.Color and Outline.EffectColor.

[image]

Then GC Alloc is generated 0.5kb every frame as above.

I do not issue it when I disabled Animator.

Why is this?
How can I avoid it?

Comment: Are you sure that your animator is only changing ` Image.Color` and `Outline.EffectColor` ?

Comment: yes. only that.